# Identify if user is based in a certain region

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my `React` app, is there a way I could detect if the user is located in Canada Quebec region?

Not just Canada, but if they are in the `Quebec` region.

Montreal falls under Quebec region for example.

Not found any online references for this.

No code to show here.

Purely a question of whether there is a library that could do this or any in built in Javascript or React.

P.S: No issues if they using vpn and faking location.

I'll take it as that is the real location.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: No need for a library, a quick search online should show you the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) (Of course there are other approaches, but that's a good place to start)

Comment: @DBS Have tried using geolocations, it doesn't work if user has switched off location services on their browser. Unless ofc no way around then that guess that is the way forward to cover those that do allow it.

Comment: If the project is small enough (costs money if you get more than 10,000 requests a month iirc) I recommend Abstract's IP Geolocation API: https://www.abstractapi.com/api/ip-geolocation-api

Comment: You can sign up for the free plan in ip2location.io for 30,000 free requests per month. You can get the province information by IP address.